# Why is RequireQualifiedAccess not working, leading to a compilation error, but not if I use open?

Tags: f#

I'm having trouble with [RequireQualifiedAccess](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/core.requirequalifiedaccessattribute-class-%5Bfsharp%5D): despite the attribute, a union case is shadowing a type. Strangely, the error only appears if I use qualified access on the enclosing module, not inside it or if I open it:

```
module Module =
    type [<RequireQualifiedAccess>] Du =
        | SomeCase

    type [<RequireQualifiedAccess>] SuperDu =
        | Du of Du

    let valid = Du.SomeCase // Valid, as expected

let invalid = Module.Du.SomeCase // Not defined?!?

open Module
let validToo = Du.SomeCase // Wait, this is valid again?
```

In the invalid line, there's first a warning that using `.Du` without qualified access is deprecated, as if I were referring to `SuperDu.Du`, then it gives an error that `SomeCase` is not defined.

I always believed that using `open X` is equivalent to prefixing `X.` to all definitions taken from that module. But it obviously isn't...?

What is going on here? Do I have to avoid this kind of name collision, despite `RequireQualifiedAccess`? Is this a compiler bug?

Comment: There is a couple of bugs related to this - https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp/issues/1253 and https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp/issues/95

Comment: @TomasPetricek Aha! Issues #1253 and #1293 describe exactly the points in this question and have both been labeled a bug by Don Syme. This answers my question. Could you make it an answer, so I can accept it?

Comment: Great - added with the links to the issues (I think you referred to #1294 rather than #1293)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an issue in the F# compiler, which has already been reported. For more information see:

- [`[<RequireQualifiedAccess>]` on a DU shadows types in the same module](https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp/issues/1253)
- [Type inference for a record/class behaves differently when module is open or not](https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp/issues/1294)